# rodbc deletes SQL Server backup file on odbcclose

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

When trying to run a backup command to MSSQL (v.14) from RODBC with the code below, the backup file is written to disk but is then deleted when the odbcClose is executed. In the RODBC documentation says: "odbcClose cleans up and frees resources." Apparently the created backup file is treated as a resource, which belongs to the session and is deleted when it is closed. Do you have any suggestions about how to do a backup in a clean way?

```
bkp_sql <- "BACKUP DATABASE staging_001 TO DISK = 'E:\bkp.bak' WITH INIT, STATS = 10;"

my_conn <- odbcConnect(gl_const.odbc_vault_connection_string)
sqlQuery(odbc_connection, inner_sql_statement)
odbcClose(my_conn)
```

Thanks,
Jordan

Comment: This doesn't happen. RODBC is just an ODBC wrapper. It doesn't *do* anything on the server, it only sends commands. `BACKUP` doesn't delete the files it generates either. Assuming the operation completed without error, either some other line deleted the file, or you're looking at the wrong drive. Did you check the *server's* `E:\` drive?

Comment: The resources referred to by the documentation are the connection itself and the buffers used by that connection. Not the database tables or backups

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos - the operation completes without error and no other lines of code are run. I am looking at the correct drive, because I see that the backup file appears while the backup procedure is running and the file grows. Then the file disappears. If I run the same code without the odbcClose the file stays as long as the session is still open.